# How to add multiple entries in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am extremely new to Tkinter. I have been trying to create something that basically calculates the average of the marks inputted. I am trying to give the user the option to choose the number of subjects, and accordingly create that many entries.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
x, y, d = 0, 0, {}
for i in range(1, int(input('Enter no of subjects')) + 1):
    sub1 = Entry(root, width=15, borderwidth=5)
    sub1.grid(row=x, column=y)
    max1 = Entry(root, width=15, borderwidth=5)
    max1.grid(row=x, column=y+2)
    sub1label = Label(root, text='Marks attained', bg='grey', fg='white')
    sub1label.grid(row=x, column=y+1)
    max_sub1label = Label(root, text='Max Marks', bg='grey', fg='white')
    max_sub1label.grid(row=x, column=y+3)
    x += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to store the data inputted each time so as to compute the percentage acquired? Or is there another method I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the values in the list and then index the list later on with the required value and get the items you wants. Here is your corrected code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def show():
    for i in range(tot_sub): # Loop through the number of subjects
        attained = attained_marks[i].get() # Get the indexed item from the list and use get()
        max_mark = max_marks[i].get()
        print(f'Attained marks: {attained}, Max marks: {max_mark}') # Print the values out

attained_marks = [] # Empty list to populate later
max_marks = [] # Empty list to populate later
tot_sub = int(input('Enter no. of subjects: ')) # Number of subjects
for i in range(tot_sub):
    sub1 = Entry(root, width=15, borderwidth=5)
    sub1.grid(row=i, column=0)
    attained_marks.append(sub1) # Append each entry to the list

    max1 = Entry(root, width=15, borderwidth=5)
    max1.grid(row=i, column=2)
    max_marks.append(sub1) # Append each entry to the list
    
    sub1label = Label(root, text='Marks attained', bg='grey', fg='white')
    sub1label.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=5)
    
    max_sub1label = Label(root, text='Max Marks', bg='grey', fg='white')
    max_sub1label.grid(row=i, column=3, padx=5)

root.bind('<Return>',lambda e: show()) # For demonstration of getting all the data

root.mainloop()
```

I have also changed the loop a bit as you don't need to initialize `x,y,d` and so on, as it can be easily achieved from inside the loop itself. I have also expanded the code so you can understand easily. Also I dont recommend using `input()` as it is for the terminal, use an `Entry` instead.

**Alternatively:** You can also use a `dict` and avoid the use of 2 lists, the dictionary would be something like `{'Alternative Marks':[att1,att2,...],'Maximum Mark':[max1,max2,...]}`, but this *would* make looping through and indexing a bit more lengthy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code really helped me. Could you explain what the *args does in the function show() ?

Comment: To be honest, nothing much, when using `bind` we need to pass `event` as a parameter. Here I just have `*args`, which means it will accept many arguments. Check my updated answer.